# Adding user locations to live map using GeoFire and Firebase

Tags: java, android, google-maps, firebase, geofire

I have developed an Android application with a user login and registraion linked to a Firebase database, I also added a list view to store the information added into the textView.

I have looked into using GeoFire as I want the current users logged in to display on a map.

I have taking a look at an example provided by Firebase and I am still unsure what to do, there isnt many tutorials on this topic.

here is the line of code which links to a public database

```
    private static final String GEO_FIRE_REF = "https://https://publicdata-transit.firebaseio.com/_geofire.firebaseio.com/_geofire";
```

I have the map displaying the loaction of the accounts on this sample.

my question is, does anybody know how I could add my users location to the map? I am new to this technology and I dont really understand alot about it.

if you need any more code or inormation let me know.